# Having hard time fetching an API with node superagent

Tags: javascript, node.js, superagent

I'm trying to get info from an API but I'm getting `undefined` as a result...

Here's the API:

```
<json>
<![CDATA[
"appearances":{"0":[45150,"inv_axe_04"]},"classs":2,"displayid":45150,"dps":11.98,"flags2":6299648,"id":32837,"level":90,"name":"3Warglaive of Azzinoth","reqclass":2601,"reqlevel":70,"slot":21,"slotbak":21,"source":[2],"sourcemore":[{"bd":1,"n":"Illidan Stormrage","t":1,"ti":22917,"z":3959}],"specs":[269,581,260,577],"speed":2.60,"subclass":7
]]>
</json>
```

And here's my code:

```
const superagent = require("superagent");

    let {body} = await superagent
    .get(`https://www.wowhead.com/item=19019&xml`);

    console.log(body[0].classs)
```

I've worked with other APIs(also with superagent) but didn't have any problems with them.

Thanks! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't know Man, but in your code class is with 3 s --> classs.

Comment: yes because it's `"classs"` in the api...

Comment: Oh ok, I checked the xml file and I stucked at the top with "class"

Comment: I have no idea why you think that `body` is going to have a useful `0` property. Nothing I can see in the documentation suggests that it will. https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/

Comment: Also, npm audit threw up a **lot** of security alerts for superagent. I wouldn't be happy using it.

Comment: Go directly to the url, it's an xml page. You'd need to parse out the json from the body, and then you could access your classs property from there.

Comment: @Quentin What should I use then?

Comment: To make HTTP requests? I'm fond of axios.

Comment: @McB How do I parse it out from the body?

Comment: @ИвайлоМ. Try searching NPM for an XML parser (And then look up JSON.parse)